# Custom IOS separator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

How is the 'or' separator below made? is it an image used in the section header?

[image]

Comment: I imagine that's just a series of UIButtons and UIViews laid out rather than a UITableView. The "Or" separator is just a UIImageView with a pre-made png file in it.

Comment: See my answer below. You need multiple delegate methods to recreate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that's really done with a table view, then it's done via a delegate method of ["`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an image used for section header.

Answer (score 0):

That login page is modifying the header/footer views of the UITableView.

When you are setting up the table view you need use the following UITableView delegate methods in order to create a header and footer view in each section of your table view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Set your custom view for the header in the section
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Set your custom view for the footer in the section
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Set the height of the header in each section
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Set the height of the footer in each section
}
```

**NOTE:** If you notice the first two methods return a UIView therefore it does not just have to be an image. You can create any custom view you want and place it in the tableView header/footer. The view could be UIKit elements, UIImage, or even made with CoreGraphics.